# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394841/replace-macbook-pro-13-early-2015-screen-with-mid-2014-screen) was just closed as "off-topic."

It seems to be on-topic to me, as it concerns only Apple hardware and whether the screen from one Mac might be useable on another model. I agree it's incomplete and requires more info to become answerable, but don't understand the "off-topic" closure reason.

Why was this question viewed as off-topic?

Comment: We have not revised our close notices since the new change. In the past we had a “basic troubleshooting” close reason that was not as useful as the current one. All of our custom close reasons probably need refining TBH. Super glad you pointed this out.

Answer (score 2):

Very good question - the hiding of custom close reason seems like either a decision that should be reviewed or we should agitate for changing the threshold - I can see no reason why we shouldn’t let a user like you see precisely why the vote to close was cast.

---

Since they are not widely visible, first the reasons chosen seem appropriate to me, so I won’t be casting a binding vote to reopen.

> Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

It doesn’t seem to be general enough to reopen without edits to clarify, but I also wouldn’t override the consensus if high rep users vote to reopen. It’s not horrible, but it’s certainly not a good hardware recommendation / repair question in the first version of that post. Edits could easily clean it up so it would be premature to delete it IMO.

We also close off site resource request questions so if this gets edited in to “help me source parts for this operation” it would likely be closed if it didn’t meet site quality standards.

Both of these close reasons are tailored to this site, so I appreciate very much asking on how / when to use them. If there’s a lot of confusion, we could flesh out meta questions to explain when these are used well and when these had to be reversed, but generally, I haven’t seen many problems with this close reason in the last 24 months here.

Comment: It doesn't help that "off-topic" is the only close reason which allows site-specific details.

Comment: And it IMHO also doesn't help that low-rep users can't see the detailed reason behind a hold. Makes it unnecessarily hard for them to help in improving a question, and to learn about on/off topic.

Comment: Yes @nohillside I have not looked at the new functionality where we can give some wording to the OP - other different wording to the high rep users, etc... I’ve added a preamble - we might need to get some more consensus and rejuggle the close reasons if there’s more than a few instances where it’s not helping as much as we hope or think close notices can. Too little data for me to have an opinion yet, overall or specifically, though.

Comment: This won‘t help with the lowrep users though

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that in its present form, the question is unanswerable. OTOH, it might be made answerable fairly easily, and I'd support a revision to the "closed" message to more completely present that the OP should both a) state what research has been done, and b) provide more technical/operational details of the setup and situation sought to be remedied.

Comment: Cool - hopefully people know they can edit closed questions since there is an Edit control visible. Food for thought on if we can get a change here or need the entire code base to improve or wait for people to read the friendly manual...

Answer (score 2):

For the users without sufficient reputation to see the exact wording of why why this was closed see below for the exact text:

> Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

There’s a few things that pop out immediately:

1. It would be immensely helpful for newer (if not all) users to see the close reasons instead of guessing as to why something is on-topic or off-topic Apple
2. I wholeheartedly agree with the close reason for the question. In my opinion it is not a good one if somebody has the technical skill to swap displays from one machine to another they should have the basic research skills to find out if those different displays are indeed compatible in fact there are several questions that I have personally answered here that go on to show how to do this exact research

- [Replace MacBook Pro screen with Screen from old MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351339/119271)
- [Is it possible to connect a 15" MacBook Pro screen to a 13" MacBook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/359638/119271)
- [Plugging MacBook Pro's display assembly onto MacBook Air Logic Board](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277425/plugging-macbook-pros-display-assembly-onto-macbook-air-logic-board/277429#277429)
- [Can I use any hardware on MBP retina late 2012 on a MBP mid 2012 (non retina)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/353014/119271)

> I agree that in its present form, the question is unanswerable.

No.  This question as written is entirely answerable if a modicum of due diligence is employed and given the scope of this undertaking, a *significant* amount if due diligence should be taken here.

- The 13” Retina Display for the Early 2013 to Mid 2014 model has a PN# of 661-8153
- The 13” Retina Display for the 2015 model has a PN# of 661-02360

What would mske this a much better question is if the OP were to list out all of the research he had done previously then ask what the specific differences are like pin outs of the LVDS connectors. There is an obvious reason there are different part numbers for the early 2013 through mid 2014 model years then there are for the 2015 model year.

The problem with the question in its current form is not the question per se, it is somebody who may answer it by simply looking at images found on the internet of the various connectors and saying “Yup this work.”